# Return names of columns with highest values across a specific subset of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, max

I have a dataset with over 300 variables. I am trying to generate a new variable which will show the name of the column in each observation that has the highest value over a specific group of columns. Specifically, for each row, I want to return the name of the column between columns 27 and 168 that has the highest value.

I tried

```
df$maxcol <- colnames(df)[max.col(df[c(27:168)], ties.method = "first")]
```

but that is returning both the names of columns I'm trying to exclude (i.e. 1-26, 169+) and the names of columns that do not have the highest value for that observation.

Comment: Would you kindly provide a representative subset of the data?

Comment: Your `colnames(df)` also need to be subseted. `colnames(df)[27:168][max.col(df[27:168], ties.method = "first")]`

Answer (score 1):

In your query, `colnames(df)` should also give a range so that it gets the column names within the specified range.

Updated Query:

```
df$maxcol <- colnames(df)[27:168][max.col(df[27:168],ties.method = "first")]
```